# How do I wait until query is completed in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, synchronization, blocking

I'm trying to return a boolean value if the query is successful but kotlin is asynchronous.

```
private fun checkDidAdd(geoPoint: GeoPoint, fullAddress: String):Boolean {
        var added = false
        scope.launch {
            val docRef = db.collection("listings")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                    for (document in result) {
                        //todo
                        }
                            added = true
                    }



                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
                }
            println("done!!")
        }

        return added
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Kotlin` itself isn't Asynchronous. Your function however is async, so you can't just return a `Boolean`. One way to achieve this is to create an interface. For ex:

```
interface ResultListener {
    fun onResult(isAdded: Boolean)
    fun onError(error: Throwable)
}
```

and pass it to your function:

```
private fun checkDidAdd(geoPoint: GeoPoint, fullAddress: String, resultListener: ResultListener) {
     var added = false
    scope.launch {
        val docRef = db.collection("listings")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    //todo
                    }
                    resultListener.onResult(true)
                }



            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                resultListener.onError(exception)
            }
        println("done!!")
    }

    return added
}
```

If you don't wanna work with interfaces and don't care about error and since you're using kotlin you can do something like this:

```
private fun checkDidAdd(geoPoint: GeoPoint, fullAddress: String, onResult: (Boolean) -> ()):Boolean {
    var added = false
    scope.launch {
        val docRef = db.collection("listings")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    //todo
                    }
                       onResult(true)
                }



            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
        println("done!!")
    }

    return added
}
```

Comment: thanks!
the compilier required me to have a type so i added Unit and it worked
private fun checkDidAdd(geoPoint: GeoPoint, fullAddress: String, onResult: (Boolean) -> (Unit)):Boolean {

Comment: good idea. thank you